# Elastic search complex acl

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to implement document filtering in elastic search by rather complex ACL implementation. Documents are organized into folders and ACL of each node is computed from it's and all of it's ancestors ACLs. When resolving access of certain security principal, ACL of ancestor closest to current node is used.

Let's assume this is the document I'd like to store:

```
{
    "id":"2",
    "acl":[
        {
            "priority":"0",
            "name":"g1",
            "allowed":true
        },
        {
            "priority":"1",
            "name":"g2",
            "allowed":false
        },
        {
            "priority":"2",
            "name":"g3",
            "allowed":true
        }
    ]
}
```

Acl contains combined permissions of various security principals. Name is name of security principal, priority is distance from current document (0 is document ACL, 1 is direct parent ACL). User, who is member of g2, can only access this document, if he's also member of g1. If user is not member of g2, he can access the document if he's member of either g1 or g3.

How should I store something like this in Elastic search, so I would be able to filter out documents user is not allowed to access and what would the queries be like?

Comment: can't a member of g2 access the document if he is the member of g3 ?

Comment: No, g3 gives him access to some folders above folder on which g2 deny is applied. If he's in g2, that access control has precedence on any folder below it.